# jQuery namespacing and using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm having trouble with my object/function scope and the general understanding of something.  I'm calling a jQuery function in doc ready like so:

```
$("#interactiveQA .actionTile").on('click',function(){
    $(this).activeTiles("init");
});
```

I then create the script like so here:

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {
        init: function() {
            var tileClicked = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    };

    $.fn.activeTiles = function(method) {

        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.slider');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**Here is what I'm looking to find out.  As technically as possible, can you please explain why var tileClicked = $(this)attr('id') does not work in its current location?  Can you also please explain in technical detail what you would do differently or best practice, etc.?**

Comment: You mean `$(this).attr('id');`, right?

Comment: yes, I updated the question.  That typo isn't the issue as I re-typed it for the stack Q

Comment: The code seems to work OK: http://jsfiddle.net/G4K7S/

Comment: @David - Thank you for pointing that out.  I was doing something slightly different in my code than what I posted to this stack and it helped me realize it wasn't my $(this) causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Typo:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Note the `.`

Comment: updated question, but doesn't solve stack.  thx

Answer (score 1):

This is usually how I try to setup a plugin's constructor:

```
$.fn.whatever = function (method) {
    var args = arguments;
    var argss = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);

    return this.each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if (methods[method]) {
            methods[method].apply($this, argss);
        }
        else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
            methods.init.apply($this, args);
        }
        else {
            $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.whatever");
        }
    });
};
```

I'm not sure if it'll fix your problem, but I haven't had trouble with it in the past...

Comment: can you throw me a comment or two explaining why you prefer this method of writing the $.fn?  Thanks-

Comment: Hmm, well I honestly forget why I differentiate between `args` and `argss`, but using `return this.each(function () {});` allows for multiple elements to be selected in the original jQuery, and every one of them having your plugin be applied to them. For example, if you want to select all elements that have a class "testing-class", and have your plugin be applied to all of them (say, a tooltip), then you would use `$(".testing-class").testPlugin({"a": "b"});`, and you would need the `return this.each`. Does that make sense? It's also to continue the chaining provided by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If your `this` inside `init` is already a jQuery object, maybe you shouldn't use `$(this)`, but instead simply write `this`, like this:

```
     init : function( ) { 
       var tileClicked = this.attr('id');
     }
```

Comment: It's okay to double-wrap jQuery objects though

Comment: If I do this.attr('id') I get hit with a JS error - uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'attr'